# Python: A more Pythonic way to loop through grid classifications

Tags: python, for-loop

I have an 11-by-11 size grid that is placed over a scatter plot. The scatter plot is of 100 randomly generated pairs. Within each grid space, is a classification type, where:

Type A is greater than 0, but less than 0.5 in both the X and Y axes,
Type B is greater than 0.5, but less than 1.5 in both the X and Y axes
ect...

I want to know how many points are within each grid space, as well as the pairs that exist in that grid space. This part isn't a problem, I just want to know if there is a more pythonic way to write my loop, since I don't want to have to write an if statement for each grid space.

My script is as follows:

```
    TypeA = []
    TypeB = []

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca()
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0.5, 10.5, 1))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0.5, 10.5, 1))

    for ii in range(100):
        RNumX = randint(0, 10)
        RNumY = randint(0, 10)

        print RNumX, RNumY

        hold(True)
        plot1 = plt.scatter(RNumX, RNumY)

        if RNumX >= 0 and RNumX < 0.5:
            if RNumY >= 0 and RNumY < 0.5:
                PairA = (RNumX, RNumY)
                TypeA.append(PairA)

            elif RNumY >= 0.5 and RNumY < 1.5:
                PairB = (RNumX, RNumY)
                TypeB.append(PairB)

    SumA = len(TypeA)
    SumB = len(TypeB)

    print TypeA, SumA
    print TypeB, SumB

    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Is better to supply runnable code (with import statements, etc).  Also if there are any other types than A and B, you need to specify their criteria.  Note, randint generates integer values so instead of "if RNumX >= 0 and RNumX < 0.5:" you can say "if RNumX == 0:"  with same effect.  Also your code disagrees with text; in the code, TypeB counts cases where RNumX==0 and RNumY==1.  Do you mean to instead count cases where RNumX == RNumY ?

Answer (score 1):

You could make Type a matrix and round the values to find your indices:

```
from random import random

# An 11 x 11 matrix of lists
Type = 11 * (11 * ([],),)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0.5, 10.5, 1))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0.5, 10.5, 1))

for ii in range(100):
    # If you want to use floats in stead of ints
    RNumX = 0.5 + 10 * random()
    RNumY = 0.5 + 10 * random()

    print RNumX, RNumY

    hold(True)
    plot1 = plt.scatter(RNumX, RNumY)

    # Round the coordinates to find the indices
    Type[int(RNumX + 0.5)][int(RNumY + 0.5)].append((RNumX, RNumY))

# Print all buckets as your snippet implies
for x in Type:
    for y in x:
        print y, len(y)

# Print only buckets with both values in the same range as your question implies
for x in range(11):
    print Type[x][x], len(Type[x][x])

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the bisect module to avoid those if statements. Here is a quick-and-dirty example.

```
from functools import total_ordering
import bisect

@total_ordering
class Point:
  def __init__(self, X, Y):
    self.X = X
    self.Y = Y

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.X == other.X and self.Y == other.Y

  def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.X < other.X and self.Y < other.Y

print [(float(x)/2, float(x)/2) for  x in xrange(0, 23)]
```

[(0.0, 0.0), (0.5, 0.5), (1.0, 1.0), (1.5, 1.5), (2.0, 2.0), (2.5, 2.5), (3.0, 3.0), (3.5, 3.5), (4.0, 4.0), (4.5, 4.5), (5.0, 5.0), (5.5, 5.5), (6.0, 6.0), (6.5, 6.5), (7.0, 7.0), (7.5, 7.5), (8.0, 8.0), (8.5, 8.5), (9.0, 9.0), (9.5, 9.5), (10.0, 10.0), (10.5, 10.5), (11.0, 11.0)]

```
points = [Point(float(x)/2, float(x)/2) for  x in xrange(0, 23)]
types = [chr(x) for x in xrange(65, 91)]
print types
```

['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

```
print types[bisect.bisect(points, Point(0.1, 0.1)) - 1]
```

A

```
print types[bisect.bisect(points, Point(0.6, 0.6)) - 1]
```

B